# Flow of current across the cross section of a wire

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

A current of 5ampere is flowing wire which is thick at one end and narrow at another will the current be the same at botht the ends or different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the same. Current is the total charge per second. Charge can be measured in Coulombs or number of electrons. The number of electrons passing by per second is the same for both ends. For every electron in one end, and electron comes out the other.

Current density is different. It measures the current per square meter. Though current per square millimeter might be a better unit for a wire. In the fat end the current is spread out over many square millimeters. Each square millimeter doesn't have all that many electrons passing by per second. In the narrow end, a square millimeter has more electrons per second.

The word current is used for water flowing in a stream in a slightly different way. Thinking about a water current can confuse the issue. In water, current is just the velocity of the water.

If you have a pipe that is fat on one end and narrow at the other, water has to move faster at the narrow end.